# Upload MP3 File via PUT to S3 results in empty file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, file-upload, put

I think I am not getting something:
This does not work for me:

```
        await fetch(url, {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "audio/mpeg",
          },
          body: "~/Downloads/my-audio.mp3",
        })
```

Am I not supposed to give the path for the `body` property? Something seems to be uploaded to s3, but I can't play it and it seems like its an empty file. How can I load the file here, without asking the user to specify one? I know the location of the file and will always overwrite it, so I just need to always send the same file.

Comment: This is sending the string "~/Downloads/my-audio.mp3" to the server instead of the contents of the file at that path. If this is from a web browser, keep in mind that you don't have access to the filesystem; you can't just call some function `readFile("~/Downloads/my-audio.mp3")`, that would allow people to just steal files from users' systems who visit a malicious webpage. Instead you must prompt the user for the file, e.g. with an `<input>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had hoped it wasn't that... The user in this case is recording a voice recording in the browser, is there a way to access this file directly (as a blob or something)? Or would the user have to save it and then select it again after having recorded it?

Comment: Yes, the body can be a `Blob` object, they don't need to download the file to reupload it. You should probably post another question if you need help with that.

Comment: I figured it out now, thanks a lot. If you want to submit your initial comment as an answer to my question, I would gladly pick that as my answer. Thank you!!